# Contouring a binary mask with OpenCV / Python

Tags: python, opencv, contour

With Python and OpenCV I am detecting contours of a binary mask:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mask = np.zeros(20000, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(100, 200)
mask[5:-5,5:-5] = 255
mask[10:70,40:80] = 0
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='Greys_r', interpolation='none')

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), 
                                          cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
                                          offset=(0, 0))
```

Resulting in an expected behaviour :

```
plt.subplot(122)
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (127, 127, 127), 2)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='Greys_r',  interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image: Simple opencv contouring]

However, I cannot seem to understand the result of a full activated mask :

```
mask = np.ones(20000, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(100, 200)
mask *=255
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),
                                            cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
                                            offset=(0, 0))

print contours[0]
```

Which produces:

```
(1   1), (1  98), (198 98), (198 1)
```

instead of `(0 0), (0 99), (199, 99), (199, 0)`

Why is opencv findcontours behaving like that, with an offset of 1?

Comment: By executing exactly your last snippet of code, I get (0 0), (0 99), (199, 99), (199, 0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until OpenCV 3.1 `findContours` has [this wierd behaviour](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4374) on borders, also stated in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a):

> Source image is modified by this function. Also, the function does not take into account 1-pixel border of the image (it's filled with 0's and used for neighbor analysis in the algorithm), therefore the contours touching the image border will be clipped.

This has [been corrected in OpenCV 3.2, which also doesn't modify the source image](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a):

> Since opencv 3.2 source image is not modified by this function.

---

As a workaround for previous releases, you can use `copyMakeBorder` to create a black (0) border of 1 pixel, and use `findContours` with an offset of `(-1,-1)`:

```
border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0 )
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(border, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, offset=(-1, -1))
```

Comment: Thank you for both approaches. I will look forward to opencv3.2 on python, and stick with your first approach in the meantime